# Calling shared services or libraries from a Polymer 1.0 custom element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

With AngularJS it's possible to share functionality between directives e.g. by injecting a common service into each directive that wishes to consume it.

I'm learning about Polymer 1.0 Custom Elements and am wondering how would a shared Javascript service/library be consumed from a custom element? The service/library isn't 3rd-party so we can modify it as we please, however it should also be possible to invoke it from legacy/non-Polymer code.

Examples of shared services could be a dialog service, or a service responsible for formatting date/time etc. It could offer any arbitrary behaviour that may also involve a remote call to, say, a web service.

What are the best practices in this regard? Is it to implement a behaviour as described in the following link?

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html

Comment: This is precisely what behaviors are for. If you look at many of the elements, they share features for a11y, selection, resizing....all which are defined as mixed in behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript functions in any Polymer element can consume any library available to them. Libraries usually expose global variables through which they can be consumed, e.g. JQuery's `$` and [lodash's](https://lodash.com/) `_` can be used globally. Similarly, with your library you can expose a global variable, e.g. my `MYLIB` through which you can consume your API, e.g. `MYLIB.formatTime`, `MYLIB.dialogService`.

Polymer behaviors are typically used for sharing common functions between polymer elements.

Answer (score 0):

Or you import a webcomponent which wraps the library you want. For lodash see for instance this one: https://github.com/Waxolunist/lodash-element